# How to use multiple conditions in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

In the following code I am trying to look for a text box in an open word document. Once that text box has been found I would also like to check to make sure the correct text is inside. This is the code that does not work and I could not figure out why.

```
Dim i as Integer

for i = 1 to Application.ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count
    if Application.ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).Name = "Text Box 2" and _
    instr(Application.ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "[Grab your reader") then
            ` Execute
    end if
next i
```

Now if I replace the *and* with another *if* statement it works.

```
Dim i as Integer

for i = 1 to Application.ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count
    if Application.ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).Name = "Text Box 2" then
        if instr(Application.ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "[Grab your reader") then
            ` Execute
        end if
    end if
next i
```

From what I understand the *and* should work exactly the same as adding a new if statement. If anyone could tell me why this happens that would be great.

Comment: What do you mean by "*this is the code that does not work*"? Do you get an error? What's the error?

Comment: Your understanding is correct, there is no reason why your first code should not work but the second would. I would investigate on the usage of `InStr()` - your second condition: this function returns a number indicating the position of the searched substring inside the string, but you're using it as if it would return a boolean. Are you missing a `InStr() > 0` instead?

Comment: I concur with Matteo, ` Instr` is used incorrectly in the first code snippet.

Comment: Instr is used correctly and in the same way in both code snippets.